# Humanity is doomed, but can increase the chance of survival by replacing all leadership with...women

Tags: story-identification

Aliens stop on a desert to repair their ship. 
A military jet tracks them and crashes there. 
The pilot learns that other races ignore humanity because the odds it will self-destruct are near 100%
The pilot asks for changes that could help.
He's told the one thing humanity can do to increase its chance of survival is to replace all the males in leadership positions with females.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if you can add more to your question to help us help you. Was this a novel? A film? A theatre play? Do the aliens show themselves? Are they humanoid? When did you read this? Was it online or from a book?

Comment: And did the jet investigating the ship crash there, or was it investigating the crash?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  When?  Is this even a written work?  Please go through the [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there's any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: I believe this is a current work called “reality”.